# Xamarin no encuentrea refrencias - Sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

Hola amigos estoy tratando de almacenar algunos datos de forma local en mi dispositivo con **SQLite** , pero me he encontrado con algunos problemas. Estuve investigando que para guardar datos en dispositivo desde Xamarin debemos hacer rutas diferentes para cada tipo de dispotivo, y que la forma en la cual direccionamos esa ruta es a través  de una interfaz. Pero llevo rato sin que xamarin encuentre mi clase referencia ... otra cosa es que no estoy obteniendo un error

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using SQLite.Net.Interop;
namespace OwsX
{
    public interface IConfig
    {
        string DbPath { get; }
        ISQLitePlatform Platform { get; }
    }
}
```

Este es mi clase de configuración para **Android** y como pueden ver no encuentra a mi otra clase **IConfig**

```js
using Android.Widget;
using SQLite.Net.Interop;

namespace OwsX.Droid {
  class Config: IConfig {
    private string dbPath;
    private ISQLitePlatform platform;
    public string DbPath {
      get {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbPath)) {
          var directory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        }
        return dbPath;
      }
    }

    public ISQLitePlatform Platform {
      get {
        if (platform == null) {
          platform = new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid();
        }
        return platform;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien sabe que esta pasando , les agradecería infinitamente su comentario. Gracias :)

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner `using OwsX;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues al final de las opciones que me sugería **VS** elegí en la que decía -  **Generar nuevo tipo** -  y me apareció la siguiente interfaz , ya aquí solo apunté al proyecto de compartido y listo referencia lista :D

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Marca tu respuesta como aceptada :D

Answer (score 1):

¿Estas seguro que tu proyecto de android referencia al proyecto PCL?
Te pongo un ejemplo tal cual lo tengo yo:

Interfaz en el PCL:
    using SQLite;

```
namespace Aplicacion.PCL.Interfaces
{
    public interface ISQLite
    {
        SQLiteAsyncConnection GetConnection();

    }
}
```

Implementacion en android:

```
using Aplicacion.PCL.Interfaces;
using System.IO;
using SQLite;
using Aplicacion.Droid.Interfaces;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(SQLiteClient))]
namespace Aplicacion.Droid.Interfaces
{
    public class SQLiteClient : ISQLite
    {
        public SQLiteAsyncConnection GetConnection()
        {
            var sqliteFilename = "db_name.db3";
            string rutaFisica = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), sqliteFilename);
            return new SQLiteAsyncConnection(rutaFisica);
        }            
    }
}
```